# How to get AppStore Connect campaign link in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, utm

I know that I can generate AppStore campaign link

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/view-app-analytics/manage-campaigns/

I have several questions about this feature:

1. How to test it in dev environment or this feature is production (AppStore) only?
2. For example user pressed on a custom campaign link, installed the application then opened it. How to get the campaign url in the app to perform things? For example to add some coins to user account if he installs app from campaign promo url? Is that possible with AppStore campaigns? If not - my only option is third party services like Firebase, Google Analytics, Branch etc.?